# Out of stack space Error

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am almost done this snippet of code, which should allow me to calculate the number of tuesdays, thursdays, saturdays and sundays in 2 date ranges.  The line "skips = ModWeekdays(NotificationDate, OrderDate, PlacementDate, ReleaseDate)" is highlighted and the error box says error '28', out of stack space. Can someone help me out here?

```
'//////This is for Valley Estimate of Demurrage Days/////////////
Public Function ModWeekdays(ByRef NotificationDate As Date, ByRef OrderDate As Date, ByRef PlacementDate As Date, ByRef ReleaseDate As Date) As Integer
Dim skips As Integer
Dim WeekendDays As Integer
Dim WeekendDays2 As Integer
'skips = 0
WeekendDays = 0
WeekendDays2 = 0


   Do While NotificationDate <= OrderDate
   If DatePart("w", NotificationDate) = 0 Then
   WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
   ElseIf DatePart("w", NotificationDate) = 2 Then
   WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
   ElseIf DatePart("w", NotificationDate) = 4 Then
   WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
   ElseIf DatePart("w", NotificationDate) = 6 Then
   WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
   End If
   NotificationDate = DateAdd("d", 1, NotificationDate)
   Loop

   Do While PlacementDate <= ReleaseDate
   If DatePart("w", PlacementDate) = 0 Then
   WeekendDays2 = WeekendDays2 + 1
   ElseIf DatePart("w", PlacementDate) = 2 Then
   WeekendDays2 = WeekendDays2 + 1
   ElseIf DatePart("w", PlacementDate) = 4 Then
   WeekendDays2 = WeekendDays2 + 1
   ElseIf DatePart("w", PlacementDate) = 6 Then
   WeekendDays2 = WeekendDays2 + 1
   End If
   PlacementDate = PlacementDate + 1
   Loop

   skips = WeekendDays + WeekendDays2
   skips = ModWeekdays(NotificationDate, OrderDate, PlacementDate, ReleaseDate)


End Function
```

Comment: Why are you always calling your function again?

Comment: because i want to export the value of the function to access.  i figured i'd use the variable "skips" to do this

Comment: if you need to return the value from the function, then the assignment statement is backwards. Try: `ModWeekdays = skips` instead of the `skips = ModWeekdays(NotificationDate, ...`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm confused.  At what point does this recursive function actually end?  Within it you have the following:

```
skips = ModWeekdays(NotificationDate, OrderDate, PlacementDate, ReleaseDate)
```

I can't work out for the life of me at what point it will stop doing this (I suspect never).  I think what is happening is you are constantly calling the function over and over again and eventually you just run out of space, hence your error.

Comment: hmmm, well my confusion comes from the fact that i am trying to get the function to equal WeekendDays + WeekendDays2.  how do i export this sum to access?

Comment: I think I'd approach it a different way.  Have a loop outside of your function (perhaps in your main method), which loops for each week you are tring to find values for.  Then call the function above to get the values and store them all in your main function and return the results (take out the recursion!).  That way you've a guarantee that it will eventually end.